# Where can I find a list of Challenges for Homefront?

Tags: achievements, homefront

I can see current challenges (a specific number of kills for a specific weapon) and their bonuses when I access the challenges screen but I'd like to find a comprehensive list. Does this list exist yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, there are XP rewards for a certain number of kills with each weapon and there are attachment rewards for a certain number of kills. Attachment rewards are only for primary weapons. Listed below (from [this page](http://www.ign.com/blogs/hardcore_hector/2011/03/23/homefront-multiplayer-guide/)) are the XP rewards and the attachment reward levels:

> **XP Rewards:**
>
> Certified: 5 Kills - 250 XP
>
> Novice: 15 Kills – 300 XP
>
> Adept: 25 Kills – 500 XP
>
> Specialist: 50 Kills - 1000 XP
>
> Marksman: 75 Kills – 2000 XP
>
> Veteran: 100 Kills - 2000 XP
>
> Sharpshooter: 150 Kills – 3000 XP
>
> Expert: 200 Kills – 5000 XP

---

> **Attachments:**
>
> Holo Scope: 5 kills
>
> Shotgun: 15 kills
>
> Silencer: 25 kills
>
> Red Dot Sight: 50 kills
>
> Grenade Launcher: 75 kills
>
> ACOG Scope: 100 kills
>
> Airburst Launcher: 150 kills
>
> EMP Launcher: 200 kills